# Access ng-message from $scope

Tags: angularjs, ng-messages

I defined a template for my validation message:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="my-custom-messages">
  <div ng-message="required">blah-blah</div>
</script>
```

And here is my form:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="myEmail" ng-model="email" required />
    <button ng-click="submit()"></button>
</form>
```

Now I want to access validation messages in the controller, like this:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.myForm.$error.required.length; i++) {
        var err = $scope.myForm.$error.required[i];
        /// how to get validation message ?
    } 
}
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: Why do you want to do it? Displaying them in the view with `ng-message` is not sufficient?

Comment: I do not want to display it. I need to access it in my controller.

Comment: define it in controller and use in html, not vice versa

Comment: Totally backwards thinking to the way angular works in general